# How can I store user inputs in an array of integers?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I do not know how many numbers the user will input, and I need the program to stop inserting the numbers in the array when it reaches the end of the line, because in the new line the user will input a number that is not related to this.

For exemple:

The user could input:

1 5 7 8 9 5

4

or:

5 4 8 9 4 2 1 3 2 4

7

The array I need would be, for exemple 1: [1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code?

Comment: If you don't know how many numbers to store, you should use an `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of a `int[]`.

Comment: Arrays are not dynamic. This means that they are fixed in size at runtime. This means that if you are not always asking the user for the same number of items then this is not the ideal data structure for your purpose. Look into java array lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement allows you to ask the user, you can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many integers you want to enter: ");
        int n = 0;
        if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            n=scanner.nextInt();
        }
        num=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter integer %d: ",i+1);
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                num[i]=scanner.nextInt();
            }           
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
How many integers you want to enter: 3
Enter integer 1: 10
Enter integer 2: 15
Enter integer 3: 20
[10, 15, 20]
```

You can also do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] num;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many integers you want to enter: ");
        int n = 0;
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            n = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        num = new int[n];
        System.out.print("Enter the integers separated by a space: ");
        String[] strNums = null;
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            strNums = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        }
        if (strNums != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                try {
                    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNums[i]);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
How many integers you want to enter: 3
Enter the integers separated by a space: 10 15 20    
[10, 15, 20]
```

However, if you want the number of integers to be unrestricted, you should use a `List` instead of an array (as the size of an array is fixed at the time of initialization) as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <Integer> intList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the integers separated by a space: ");
        String[] strNums = null;
        if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            strNums = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
        }
        if (strNums != null) {
            for (String strNum: strNums) {
                try {
                    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(strNum.trim()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(intList);

            //You can even get an array out of the list as follows:
            Integer[] nums = intList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the integers separated by a space: 10 20 30 40
[10, 20, 30, 40]
[10, 20, 30, 40]
```

Wish you all the best!

Comment: I think the question asks specifically that the user does not input the amount of integers they are entering. In your answer you require the user to input that value. If we knew the number of values we wouldnt ask this question.

Comment: thanks, the third program that you posted made the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use List to save the numbers.
If you really want an array type variable. You can create an array from the list.

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
    Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String value = reader.readLine();
String[] strArr = value.split(" ");
int intArr[]= new int[strArr.length]; 
for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++)
    intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]);
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree you ought to ask the user about the size of the array as an array is static data structure.
Use the linked list data structure.