# Echo Input using Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I’m trying to code a simple Java program entering five integers through echo input while using arrays. All I should be able to do is enter five integers, and the program just displays a message preceded by the entered numbers.  I would think that all I would need to add would be a correct array variable assignment, but I can’t find it. What does anyone suggest?

[what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVagK.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store user inputs in an array of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59413887/how-can-i-store-user-inputs-in-an-array-of-integers)

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Comment: There are multiple issue with your code, it would be better to first go through a tutorial to atleast understand the basics

Comment: [Read int from scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506109/2478398).  [Using arrays](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/arrays.html).  [Printing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/2478398).  Read through those and you should be able to come up with your own answer (and see what's wrong with the code at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw in your code, you are trying to use a variable ***n*** that has not been declared, the correct one would not be ***num.length***?

You can also use ***in.nextInt();*** for integer values.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

- `n` is not defined, perhaps you meant to use `5`.
- The array is defined in a C-style, define it like this: `int[] arrayVariableName`
- `num` is an array, so it should be named `nums`.
- To get an `int` from an input, you should call `in.nextInt()` and not `in.next()`.
- To print the contents of the array, you should first call `Arrays.toString()`.

The fixed code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 integers: ");

    int[] nums = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        nums[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("You entered: " + Arrays.toString(nums));
}
```